# Multiple webpack rules in vue.config.js - order

Tags: vue.js, webpack

When I'm using both [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) and [yaml-loader](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml-loader), It looks like the **order** plays an important role.
Any idea why?

---

*vue.config.js*

**Works:**

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.extensions.add('.yml').add('.yaml');
        config.module
            .rule('yaml')
              .test(/\.ya?ml?$/)
              .use('json-loader')
              .loader('json-loader')
              .end()
              .use('yaml-loader')
              .loader('yaml-loader')
              .end()
            .rule('raw')
              .test(/\.txt$/)
              .use('raw-loader')
              .loader('raw-loader')
              .end();
    }
```

**Does not work:**

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.extensions.add('.yml').add('.yaml');
        config.module
            .rule('raw')
              .test(/\.txt$/)
              .use('raw-loader')
              .loader('raw-loader')
              .end()
            .rule('yaml')
              .test(/\.ya?ml?$/)
              .use('json-loader')
              .loader('json-loader')
              .end()
              .use('yaml-loader')
              .loader('yaml-loader')
              .end();
```